# auto click a specific location on an iframe using javascript/html

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, click

I'm fairly new to html so basically I have an Iframe and I want it to auto click a specific location when a user enters a website.  I want it physically click the google search button  Is it possible to give a location for a click?  If so it would be helpful to display some code.  This is what i got so far.

```
<html>
<iframe src="http://www.google.com" width="700" height="500" frameborder="1">

  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>

</iframe>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think that's possible. I would consider using the google API.

Comment: If you'd run your code, you'd know google.com can't be loaded into an iframe... Also good to read: [Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can load www.google.com into an iframe, you might try adding a query string onto the end of the URL.

Something like `https://www.google.com/#q=my+search+criteria`

The user doesn't click anything, but search results are loaded (assuming Google will let you load its website in an iframe).